# Will it matter if I give to someone the IMEI or Serial number of my device?

Tags: mobile

Just as the title says, if I have for example a pocket wifi will it matter if I give the IMEI or serial number to someone who ask for it? Or maybe a crucial device that can affect your health like [implantable medical devices](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/HeartAttack/PreventionTreatmentofHeartAttack/Implantable-Medical-Devices_UCM_303940_Article.jsp)?

It is because I've watched a movie before and it involves a person providing the serial number (Am not sure) to the hacker, and the hacker because he knows the serial number of the [pacemaker](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=pacemaker&oq=pacemaker&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i61.1214j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) (Am not sure again) he is able to stop the heartbeat of the person.

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49343/what-is-the-risk-of-leaking-imei-imsi-numbers-over-a-network

Comment: Good to know that you haven't seen that Bourne-movie where he makes a copy of a SIM card.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the serial number of a pacemaker won't allow you to magically stop it.

Now, the IMEI is sometimes used for things it shouldn't really be used like authenticating you on WhatsApp (a weakness of the app). Thus, it's not recommended to go around publishing it (OTOH for instance the manufacturer will *require* you to provide it before giving support…).

Comment: Unless the pacemaker uses both wireless communication and some broken custom crypto using the serial number as a key.

Comment: Yeah, I remember that it uses wireless communication so the doctor of the person who uses it can monitor also the heart rate.

Comment: Never underestimate how badly can people misdesign things. Still, if the pacemaker is so broken it's possible to enter into it and _kill_ someone… Can we test that on the people that made it?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this depend on whether the IMEI number is used internally by the manufacturer as a key to a database of default SSIDs, auth keys, or passwords?

If that's the case then either compromising that database of authentication details (by some kind of hack externally or internally to the organisation), or a social engineering attack on customer services for example, may enable the person with access to the IMEI to gain access to the auth details..