# What harm can a leaked IMSI do?

Tags: simcard

I know that subscribers can be tracked using IMSI. I also know IMSI follows a pattern of `MCC+MNC+MSIN` where `MCC` and `MNC` parts remain static for a certain `PLMN`. What changes is the `MSIN` part. As such, by guessing a random `MSIN` and using the fixed `PLMN`, part a random IMSI can be guessed.

If an attacker guesses a random IMSI and accidentally matches my IMSI, what harm might he be able to do to me? What method might the attacker use to track my phone calls and SMS using just my IMSI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the risk of leaking IMEI / IMSI numbers over a network](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49343/what-is-the-risk-of-leaking-imei-imsi-numbers-over-a-network)

Comment: @schroeder actually this is my first question here. I have edited my question as per your suggestion. Hope this is ok now

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't change the question. Attacker has an IMSI, however it was obtained, what can be done with it? That's covered in the other question. ***How*** the IMSI was obtained does not change the scenario.

Comment: Are you assuming that the IMSI can be tracked across the network?